# Is there a function to rearrange a data frame for plotting in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, area

I have a dataframe that I want to plot via a bar chart. The data frame looks like the following:

| ID | Suitability | TA | Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Limited Suitability | Tasman | 151 |
| 3 | Suitable | Timaru | 222 |
| 3 | Limited Suitability | Timaru | 533 |
| 4 | Suitable | Grey | 1112 |
| 4 | Limited Suitability | Grey | 1234 |
| 5 | Suitable | Gore | 5426 |

```
# basic plotting
ggplot(TA_area, aes(x = TA, y = Area)) +
  geom_col()
```

TA_area refers to the df.

The data is based on the suitability for ski fields which has been created by a reclassification matrix. I'm struggling to plot as when I plot TA with Area it does the combined Area for both "Limited Suitability" and "Suitable", where as I want to create two plots where it shows Area of "Suitable" by TA. How would i go about in creating new columns of "Limited Suitability" and "Suitable" where the area value is under it for each TA.

| ID | Limited Suitability | Suitable | TA | Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 151 | NA | Tasman | 151 |
| 3 | 533 | 222 | Timaru | 755 |
| 4 | 1234 | 1112 | Grey | 2346 |
| 5 | NA | 5426 | Gore | 5426 |

I want the there to be an value under each category then an combined total in the area column. But not really sure how to go about this as I am new to coding and R.

Comment: "Limited Suitability" and "Suitable" on the same plot: `aes(x = TA, y = Area, fill=Suitability)`.  Faceted plot: `... + facet_wrap(vars(Suitability), ncol=2)`.  Separate plots: `lapply(unique(TA_area$Suitability), function(x) TA_Area %>% filter(Suitability == x) %>% ggplot(aes(x = TA, y = Area)) + geom_col()`) or `TA_area %>% group_by(Suitability) %>% group_walk(~ggplot(aes(x = TA, y = Area)) + geom_col())`.  All code untested in the absence of an MWE.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the question as I think my accidentally pretty much copied + paste the first table. The question now shows what I am loooking to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid tedious data re-transformation using `barplot` from base R.

```
barplot(Area ~ TA + Suitability, dat, beside=TRUE, col=2:5)
legend('topright', legend=sort(unique(dat$TA)), col=2:5, pch=15)
```

[image]

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), Suitability = c("Limited Suitability", 
"Suitable", "Limited Suitability", "Suitable", "Limited Suitability", 
"Suitable"), TA = c("Tasman", "Timaru", "Timaru", "Grey", "Grey", 
"Gore"), Area = c(151L, 222L, 533L, 1112L, 1234L, 5426L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```